# Can unit normal vector field be obtainable by gradient of some function?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a smooth map and $c$ is a regular value in its image. Then $\text{grad}(f)$ is the normal vector field of the hypersurface defined by $f$. Does there exist a smooth map $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that 
$$ f^{-1} (c) = g^{-1}(c) \text{ and }\|\text{grad}(g)\|=1,$$ 
i.e I am asking can I get a $g$ such that unit normal vector fields is given by the gradient of $g$? I don't have any knowledge about PDE. If the solution is affirmative and requires theory of PDE please give me a good source. Thank you.

Comment: do you ask for a specific fixed constant c, or for any regular value c?

Comment: It does not matter. Because you can always translate your g.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $c=0$, it will be easier. The set of functions wich vanishes on this hypersurface $M : f=0$ is a principal ideal generate by $f$. in other word, you have to find $g$ in the form $g(x)= h(x).f(x)$ where $h(x)\not= 0$. Differentiate, you must have $g'(x)=h(x)f'(x)$ along $M$, and taking the norm $h(x)={1\over \vert \nabla f (x)\vert }$. In other word, let $h(x)$ be any nowhere vanishing function with $h(x)={1\over \vert \nabla f (x)\vert }$ along $M$, then $h.f$ does the job. The existence of such a function in the neighborhood of $M$ is obvious (just take ${1\over \vert \nabla f (x)\vert }$. The global existence can be proven by standard methods (partition of unity, for instance).

Comment: It's not clear to me why the ideal is principle?

Comment: It is not used in the proof, btw : do you agree ?. You can prove it by using something like the Hadamard Lemma+The implicit function theorem.